# hide application files in setup file in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, installation, software-packaging

I have created a setup file using install shield limited edition for visual studio 2013. and its working. my problem is that, when my customer install the application on his machine he will be able to see the whole source code. as i saw in other application installed in windows there isn't any source code in , just a .exe file and some dll's. how couild i overcome this problem and how application that use only dll files work ?

this is my destination folder :
[image]

Comment: In a setup project, you should add only the project output(primary output), resources.etc. Be sure not to add your source code files to installer file. Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/568476/Creating-an-MSI-Package-for-Csharp-Windows-Applica)

Comment: @CuriousPen tnx, the tutorial you have linked is for visual studio 2010 , does it work for visual studio 2013 too ?

Comment: Sure it does, there are minimal changes between VS versions. Maybe Publish option is a better and simplier way. [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx)

Comment: NO. The setup project type has been discontinued as of vs2012. You have to use either InstallShield LE or something else like WiX. Publish still works (click-once installation).